# syntax highlighting in vim for *.smt files

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, smt

Why does vim highlight the letter `r` in a different color when editing `smt` files? Definitely not critical, but if anyone has a quick fix for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. (I maintain an [extended fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/SyntaxAttr.vim).) When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; (the last lines of) `:scriptnames` may help.

---

Here, the syntax script is `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/smith.vim`, and the highlighting is caused by`smithRegister`:

```
syn match smithRegister     "R[\[]*[0-9]*[\]]*"
```

Everything after the `R` is optional; together with the `:syn case ignore`, this causes any `r` to be highlighted.

I don't know anything about that language; probably those suffixes should be made mandatory; you can fix that by overriding the syntax definition in `~/.vim/after/syntax/smith.vim` (and send a patch to the original author).

To just silence this rule altogether, put this into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
highlight link smithRegister Normal
```

Comment: I can't seem to find the file `smith.vim`. my `~/.vim` does not contain any sub-folders, and my `$VIMRUNTIME` is empty.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom are you checking VIMRUNTIME inside vim or in a shell?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I checked it in the shell

Comment: @OrenIshShalom it’s only set in vim